# The installer says that there is not enough space on the disk

Tags: installation

Despite the fact that I don t have anything installed on the disk, the installer says there is not enough space in the disk. The "try option" works ok. any thoughts?

Comment: You need to provide more information about Current HDD partitions and which partition you have to install it.

Comment: Boot into the "Try option" -> open GParted -> add the hard drive information it displays to your question then we will be able to help you.

Comment: "Boot into the "Try option" -> open GParted " where do I find Gparted? sorry for my ignorance

Comment: Just open the dash (click on the ubuntu logo) and type Gparted.

Comment: i ve oppened the gparted and it says "no devices detected"

Comment: I managed to install the Ubuntu using my Mp3 player as hardrive and it worked. well, I don t have a big disk capacity but at least it works. The c: drive is still not recognizable, so I guess I still didn't find the solution. Still anyone with patience to give me some tips?

Comment: "no devices detected" surely is a hard one. You're not by chance using some *really* exotic drive setup (cheap HW-RAID-Controllers, ancient HDDs with <1GB, ...)? What is the content of your /proc/partitions file? Thumbs up for your persistance btw.

Comment: The /proc/partitions goes like this: a)major b)minor c)blocks d)name  1st row: a)8 b)0 c)8227072 c)sda  2nd row: a)8 b)1 c)6139904 d)sda1 3rd row: a)8 b)2 c)1 d)sda2  4th row: a)8 b)5 c)2084864 d)sda5. hope it s not too confusing, but I didn't manage to snapshot it.

Comment: This is indeed only one volume (Probably th USB Stick) with 2 Partitions (Technically 3, One Primary, One Logical nested inside a second Primary)

Answer (score 0):

Oh... Dang! I get it. Go to your BIOS setup and see if there is some option like ATA-Mode or something. Switch it. Then reboot, retry.

Comment: On the BIOS setup I found AHCI mode - Enable (the other option was Disable). Was this what you meant? I switch it to Disable and I reboot?

Comment: Yes, you should try that. You can always set it back without repercussions if it doesn't work out. AHCI, UHCI, OHCI... I remember that from different machines. I am not much into hardware, but if I got it correctly this is kind of the command interface which the operating system is supposed to use to communicate with the disk controller. And the BIOS can provide different types of interfaces. AHCI is one of them UHCI another, etc..

Comment: I've been switching it for a while, but with no apparent results. It still doesn't appear other hardware, apart from the audio one from the mp3 player.

Comment: So, I opened my notebook, disconnected and reconnected the internal disc, but nothing. In the application Disk Utility it appears SATA Host Adapter - 82801 GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controler [AHCI Mode]. But this isn't my disc, no?

Comment: This is the Controller, not the Disk itself. I am running out of ideas. Switching the AHCI setting sounded sooo promising.